# Novel about a girl who reincarnates after being killed by her father and a treasure related to a phoenix

Tags: story-identification, novel

It's the story of a girl that got killed by her father because of her step sister, and a treasure related to a phoenix. She get reincarnated in the same world in the body of a girl with missing parents, then she went looking for her parents and her brother and she tamed the 4 mythical beasts.

I also remember that in the story she found some white haired guy (male lead). Her parents (after reincarnation) left her with her paternal family to protect her but they bullied her.

Her brother joined some sect (he's a prodigy).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: It was last year so I don't remember where

Answer (score 13):

I found it .

It's [*Evil Emperor's Wild Consort*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41149088-evil-emperor-s-wild-consort) by Xiao Qiye

> Orphaned, born a weakling, and being the infamous good-for-nothing of Azure Dragon Country. Gu Ruoyun was the shame of the proud Gu household. Falsely accused of a crime she did not commit, she was betrayed by her family and beaten to death by her own grandfather. But life took a fateful twist on that very day — she was revived.
>
> Newly awakened, she is now the Master of an ancient treasure that resides within her body. Precious cultivation pills, treasures beyond her wildest imagination and spiritual beasts, all within her grasp... She is the apple of the eye of all under the heavens, including that of a mysterious, handsome man.
>
> Now she only has one goal — to conquer the world.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this. :)

Answer (score 5):

Could be [Phoenix Reborn: The Peerless Fourth Lady](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/phoenix-reborn-the-peerless-fourth-lady/)

> In the protagonist Qilian Qingyan’s previous life, she was married to
> the Crown Prince since youth, and ruled over the six palaces for more
> than 10 years. In the end however, she met her demise at the betrayal
> of her younger sister and a fire burned everything to ashes. She vowed
> to extract her revenge on all those that’ve made her suffer. However
> instead of death, she later wakes up in the body of a young girl named
> Su Qingyan, 5 years from the day of her death. Sensing this is an
> opportunity from the heavens, she slowly plots out her revenge against
> those from her previous life.

Comment: No I'm sorry this isn't it.

Comment: In the beginning of this novel her fiance kill her brother than try to steal some treasure that her maternal grandfather gave her

Comment: They called her gu girl in the novel

Comment: @ManouLa - please edit that information into the question, rather than leaving it as comments on an answer.  When you are looking for a book that will help people who are trying to help you identify it.  Afterwards, it can help others looking for the same (or a similar) book.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Born of Embers](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/38319561) by Quinn Arthurs?

> I always knew I was different. I’d thought it had to be hidden - to stay a secret. I didn’t know my secret would become the key to my survival. Turning eighteen and getting accepted into college brings me everything I need to escape from the nightmares of my past but I never could have imagined my nightmares - and dreams - were just beginning.

Main character is killed by her father and reborn due to her relation to the phoenix of mythology.

Comment: No I'm sorry it's more of a historical fictionnal novel with an emperor and sects